# How do I display the results of a python function in Django's base.html file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, radix

I have the following function that is currently defined in my `views.py`:

```
def display_path_url(request):
    return HttpResponse("Current Path: %s" % request.path)
```

Say I am accessing `127.0.0.1:8000/product_list`, I will have `product_list/` printed.

I need this information to be printed on every rendered page in *Django*. This is why I want this function to be called in `base.html`.

How do I do that?

Thank you for your help.

PS: I tried to find an answer from other Stackoverlow posts but could not find any solutions. I hope this question is not a duplicate of some other question.

Answer (score 0):

`request` variable is available in Django templates. You can access it from anywhere. Not only `base.html`. Like this -

```
{{ request.path }}
```

[Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request).

Answer (score 0):

As karthikr and Bibhas already mentionned you don't have much to do to access the current `request` in a template (assuming the template is rendered using a `RequestContext`, cf  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

As a more general answer, if you want to make a function available from any template, then the best way is to write a custom filter or template tag as explained here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/